# Video compression in OSX using avassets how to achieve?

Tags: objective-c, macos

so I am using this function to compress my video saved in .mov format on disk.
Input url is the video I have saved in my disk.
Output url is where I want to export my compressed video.

```
- (void)compressVideo:(NSURL*)inputURL
            outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL
              handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))completion  {
    AVURLAsset *urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:urlAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        completion(exportSession);
    }];
}
```

I am calling this function like this

```
NSURL* outPutURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/anyFolder/" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];

    outPutURL = [[outPutURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[@"MacTestApp-" stringByAppendingString:@"test"]] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"m4v"];
    NSLog(@"upload = %@",outPutURL);
  ;


    [self compressVideo:inputURL outputURL:outPutURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *completion) {
        if (completion.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
            NSData *newDataForUpload = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:outPutURL];

            NSLog(@"Size of new Video after compression is (bytes):%lu",(unsigned long)[newDataForUpload length]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"completion.status %ld ",(long)completion.status);
              NSLog(@"completion.status %ld ",(long)AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed);
        }
    }];
```

But always my completion status is failed.. why its happening?

Comment: Because the app is sandboxed?

Comment: no it is not this is OS X app not iOS